# Android Fatal Exception Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, json, for-loop

Hey I am new at android developing, and I am having a big problem with my application but I can't find the error, can someone help me?

**I am getting a null pointer exeption.**

MainActivity.java: http://www.codeshare.io/ywC71 
ApiConnector.java: http://www.codeshare.io/u6FVk

Error: [image]

I don't know what I did wrong please help me, thanks, cheers.

Comment: Add you code in the question and not as link, if the link becomes invalid, question will also become invalid here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `jsonArray` object is `null`. Check its value where you are getting it from. And write your loop like this:

```
if(jsonArray != null){
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length ; i++)
         .....
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is given in the log files itself. If you chek thoroughly the line is given in your logcat,

> "at net.competitiveworld.sqllasttry.MainActivity.setTextToTextView(MainActivity.java:32)"

So, line number 32 of your MainActivity has the issue. If you double click on the line in Logcat, it will lead you to that particular line,

```
"for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){"
```

And in this line, there is only one object which can be null, 'jsonArray'. So when you are trying to get length() of a null object you are getting NullPointerException. You should add check the null as **ZygoteInit** mentioned.
You can check with the URL/server why it is giving you null value.